# Binding DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to array of booleans

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm currently trying to build a DataGridView in a Windows Form to display to a user a list of settings that they can turn on and off.  The DatGridView will have two columns, the first column will describe the setting and the second column will containg a check box allowing the user to turn the setting on or off.  So for example the DataGridView would look like:

```
| Descriptions        |   Set   |
---------------------------------
| Description 1       |  true   |
| Description 2       |  false  |
| Description 3       |  false  |
...
```

In my project settings I currently have a list of booleans, Pref1, Pref2, Pref3 etc which I'd like to bind to the CheckBoxes within the DataGridView so that they can be manipulated automatically without me having to do any manual checks whenever a cells value has been edited and so I can save the changes between different instances of the application.

I tried searching for a few solutions and came across the following and added it to the forms constructor:

```
// Build preference dictionary
Dictionary<String, bool> Preferences = new Dictionary<String, bool>();
preferences.Add("Description 1", Settings.Default.Pref1);
preferences.Add("Description 2", Settings.Default.Pref2);
....

// Copy dictionary to list
List<KeyValuePair<String, bool>> PreferenceList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, bool>>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, bool> item in Preferences)
    PreferenceList.Add(item);

// Set the GridView DataSource and values displayed in each column
GridView.AutoGenerateColuns = false;
GridView.DataSource = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<String, bool>>(PreferenceList);
GridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Key";
GridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Value";
```

When the form loads the DataGridView populates as expected but the CheckBoxes in the second column can't be manipulated.  After some debugging I've notcied the second column becomes ReadOnly when I set the DataPropertyName to "Value" and I can't change this ReadOnly setting without throwing an exception.

Is there any way around this readonly issue?  I've also read and thought about creating my own Preference class something along the lines of:

```
public Class Preference
{
    public String Description  { get, set }
    public bool Selected  { get, set }
}
```

And then creating an array of these preferences, binding each Preference's 'Selected' property to one of the booleans in my Settings class and then setting the Preference array as the DataGridViews DataSource.  Is this a viable solution or is there maybe another alternative that I'm not considering/aware of?

Sorry for the essay of a question but I just like to try and explain everything so theres no confusion in what I'm asking :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A list of preference would be a nice way to go about

Comment: Do you mean the array of Preference classes that I mentioned as an alternative or using the List collection currently being used?

Comment: Yes similar to what Jacob suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GridView.DataSource = Preferences 
   .Select(p => new Preference {Description = p.Key, Selected = p.Value})
   .ToList();
GridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Description";
GridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Selected";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jacob Seleznev.  I've managed to get it working with the suggestion you made, although I had to make a tweak or two.  p.Key and p.Value don't exist in the Preference class so I'm assuming that was a typo unless I'm missing something?


I just need to figure out now how to bind the Selected property to a boolean in the Settings.Default namespace for it to work as I'd like (any suggestions would be greatly appreciated) but for now I'm able to get what I want done with this solution so thanks very much.

Comment: p is not Preference p is KeyValuePair<string, bool>